# Infinite scroll js with backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, infinite-scroll

I'm stuck with this issues for 3 consecutive days, I have been trying to use 
 https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll to make scrolling in my backbone project.

I attempted to find an answer to my question with the search engine but i was unable to. I am a beginner developer with `backbone.js`.

View of Item List :

```
var ItemList = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
    },
    render: function(){
        this.$el.empty();
        this.collection.each(function(_itemData){
            var itemList = new ItemView({model : _itemData});
            this.$el.append(itemList.el);
        },this);
    }
});
```

View of Item List View :

```
render: function(){
   var _itemList = _.template(ItemListTem);
   this.$el.html(_itemList);
   var _itemObj = _item.getItemSearches(this.options.key);
   var itemColletion = new ItemCollection(_itemObj);
   var itemListView = new ItemList({collection : itemColletion, el : '.itemListContainer'});
   itemListView.render();
});
```

Item Collection :

```
var itemCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : itemModel,
    url : RootWebsite
});
```

And I divided item list and item template into different html file.

Item list template :

```
<div class="itemListContainer"></div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#appendItem').infinitescroll({
        navSelector     : "#next:last",
        nextSelector    : "a#next:last",
        itemSelector    : "#appendItem p",
        debug        : true,
        loadingImg   : "/img/loading.gif",
        loadingText  : "Loading new posts...",
        animate      : true,
        donetext     : "I think we've hit the end" ,
        appendCallback  : false,
        path: ["http://localhost/Website/#itemlist"]
    }, function(json, opts) {
        var page = opts.state.currPage;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Item template :

```
<div class="itemTemplate">
       <!-- item elements in here -->
</div>
```

There are hundreds of item in the collection, so I would like to integrate a scrolling plugin to my item list.

`console.log(opts.state.currPage)` increase page number 1,2,3... when scrolling reached the corner of windows and it doesn't have any effect on the list of my view.

I wonder, do I have to add something else to the collection, or how can the scroll separate the full data into small pieces.

I'm sorry if I'm a bit noob! Welcome to your question and thanks for any help with my problem you can provide to me!

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you itemView.render() renders everything. Make it accept index parameter, and splice the collection

```
render: function(index){
    //this.$el.empty();
    var loadElements = index * 10;
    _(this.collection.models.splice(loadElements, loadElements+10)).each(function(_itemData){
        var itemList = new ItemView({model : _itemData});
        this.$el.append(itemList.el);
    },this);
}
```

then your plugin should call render

```
}, function(json, opts) {
    var page = opts.state.currPage;
    listView.render(page-1) // you mentioned that it starts from 1
});
```

});